# Cannot find android native code implementation at runtime

Tags: android, java-native-interface

I have been working on integrating our (*university*) research code into an android app using Android Studio.

I have created a native java wrapper like this (*simplified for readability*) :

```
package fr.uni.researchdemo;

public class Wrapper {
     static {
          System.loadLibrary("nativelib");
     }
     public native long ReadBatch(String strBatchFile, String strInputFile, String strLogFile);
}
```

I then generated a header file which transforms the signature to be this :

```
JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL Java_fr_uni_researchdemo_Wrapper_ReadBatch
  (JNIEnv *, jclass, jstring, jstring, jstring, jstring);
```

I then proceeded to write the CMake script and compile/build the application.

The native library (so) is built as a SHARED library and I have verified that it is indeed packaged into the apk (using the APK Analyzer).

Everything builds fine and I can run the application.

However, upon the first call to `Wrapper.ReadBatch`, the application crashes with the following messages in logcat :

```
2021-09-14 16:32:00.202 26338-26396/fr.uni.researchdemo E/art: No implementation found for
 long fr.uni.researchdemo.Wrapper.ReadBatch(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String) 
 (tried Java_fr_uni.researchdemo.Wrapper_ReadBatch and ...)
2021-09-14 16:32:00.207 26338-26396/fr.uni.researchdemo E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-6
```

I am at a loss as to know where to look and what needs adjusting.

Can any experts help in this matter ?

---

**EDIT**

As per Michaels requests, I have added the package name above and here is the cpp wrapper code :

```
JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL Java_fr_uni_researchdemo_Wrapper_ReadBatch
  (JNIEnv *pEnv, jobject obj,
   jstring strBatchFile, jstring strInputFile, jstring strOutputFile, jstring strLogFile)
{
    char* pBatch = (char*)pEnv->GetStringUTFChars(strBatchFile, nullptr);
    char* pInput = (char*)pEnv->GetStringUTFChars(strInputFile, nullptr);
    char* pOutput = (char*)pEnv->GetStringUTFChars(strOutputFile, nullptr);
    long lResult = 0;

    lResult = read_batch(pBatch, pInput, pOutput);

    return lResult;
}
```

In addition, I have run the `nm -D` command on the native library and the function `read_batch` is indeed listed there.

Comment: Please run `nm -D` on your .so file. Is your native function listed in the output with the same exact name as in your source code?

Comment: Also, you haven't shown us the .cpp or .c file where the native function is defined, nor the line in the Java file where the package name is set.

Comment: Thank you @Michael for your questions. I have updated the question text with the information you requested.

Comment: Does `nm` confirm the existence of the Java_..._ReadBatch function?

Comment: Hi @Botje, yes, just ran the command ```nm -D```on the generated wrapper library and the function is there.

Comment: Add a basic log message to the JNI_Onload function and see if that appears in logcat.

Answer (score 1):

Just found the reason !

For a reason unbeknown to me, the signature between the header and the implementation were not the same.

The header declares :

```
JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL Java_fr_uni_researchdemo_Wrapper_ReadBatch
  (JNIEnv *, jclass, jstring, jstring, jstring, jstring);
```

and the implementation has

```
JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL Java_fr_uni_researchdemo_Wrapper_ReadBatch
  (JNIEnv *pEnv, jobject obj,
   jstring strBatchFile, jstring strInputFile, jstring strOutputFile, jstring strLogFile)
```

Note the seconde parameter.  In the header it is a **jclass** and in the implementation it is a **jobject**.

In addition, I had to add, in the implementation code, `extern "C"`.

Don't know why there was that difference on the second parameter, but along with the absence of `extern "C"`, it would explain why the runtime linker could not find the function.

All is OK now.

Thanks to Michael and Botje for their input.

Comment: Is it possible you forgot to `#include` the generated header file? Because the header should set up `extern "C"` for you *and* make sure the prototype matches.

Comment: No, the include was always there and indeed declared the functions as being ```extern "C"```, yet I still had to decorate the functions in the cpp with the same.  One of those wierd things that makes you waste a day searching for a reason - well, it works now and thats what counts !

Comment: Ah yes, you should make sure that your implementation always matches the header file and, in turn, the Java code. Since your method is non-static, it should take a `jobject`, not a `jclass`. Regenerating the header should take care of that.